# How to finish clean banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, banner

I need help with how to finish this very simple and clean banner.

For the text, I think it is okay.  I need change each text in at same time as the background-color.

The banner has 3 steps, 3 different background colors and text (if possible with fade effect).

I don't have the solution

Please help me.

PS: This is my example work: [Work Beta](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYJsK/195/)

```
<span id="example" style="background:red">TEXT 1</span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your jsFiddle example, you can do:**

```
var texts = ["TEXT 1", "TEXT 2", "TEXT 3"];
var colors = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'];
var count = 0;
function changeText() {
    $("#example").text(texts[count]);
    $("#example").css({'background-color': colors[count]});
    count < 3 ? count++ : count = 0;
}
setInterval(changeText, 1000);
```

Also make sure that the first element is the color array matches the initial color of your element you specify using `style="background:red"` Also use `background-color` instead of `background`. See comment below for explanation

## [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4g5g/)

<sub>[and one more which is slightly more optimized](http://jsfiddle.net/3YevU/1/)</sub>

---

## Explaination

You can use jQuery to change the css property of an element:

```
$("#example").css({'property_name': 'value'});
```

To change the color, you can do

```
$("#example").css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
```

---

## Fadding Background-Color

To do the fading you'll need to use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) 
Here is how you do it:

```
$('#example').animate({backgroundColor: '#FF0000'}, 'slow');
```

Comment: Mention that he has to remove `background: red` from the html code. `background property overrides `background-color` property.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav If he remove the `background: red`, then when the page loads, the background will be transparent up until the javascript runs. He could iniate the bg color when the page load but that is generally bad practice

Comment: Then mention, that he have to set `background-color: red` instead of `background: red`. As I said — `background` property overrides `background-color` property, whith is set up by jQuery.

Comment: Great ! Thanks !!!

Little questions... 

For put a little cool fade effect between each color. is possible ?
and
for the bg colors is possible to put a css background Gradient ? 

Tnx

Comment: @MyFirstLog You can indeed do the gradients, you just need to add the appropriate css styles. Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/qpUwj/ For the fading effect, you can't do it easily with jQuery. Ull need to use jQueryUI. Have a look at my edited answer

Comment: @Krimson Thank you.  Sorry i'm very novice :-(

Comment: @Krimson Where place the .animate for fade effect in each color ?

Comment: @MyFirstLog in your `changeText()` function. Replace `$("#example").css({'background-color': colors[count]});` with the `.animate(...)` version. it would be better if you started a new question and also accept this one if you like this